# Postgis using st_geometry linestring on column

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, linestring, spatial-query

I'm trying to create a linestring based on a value in a column in PostGIS. My code looks like this:

```
create view left_span as 
SELECT st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(line_att.wkt_left)', 27700) as geom
FROM line_att
```

It creates the view but without any results.

When I try to select just LINESTRING:

```
SELECT st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(line_att.wkt_left)', 27700) as geom
FROM line_att
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry HINT:  "LINESTRING(li" <--
parse error at position 13 within geometry
********** Error **********
```

My column structure looks like this:

```
wkt_left
608499.156438 127925.765696, 608583.734491 127621.137605
609186.961722 128406.984816, 609287.145785 128550.322806
```

Calling just one row works fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue here is with your WKT construction:

```
SELECT st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING(line_att.wkt_left)', 27700)
```

will try to create a geometry from the WKT

```
'LINESTRING(line_att.wkt_left)'
```

which is invalid.

Try using string concatenation to ensure the wkt_left values are being inserted into the string:

```
SELECT st_geomfromtext('LINESTRING('||line_att.wkt_left||')', 27700) as geom
FROM line_att
```

This should result in the WKT

```
'LINESTRING(608499.156438 127925.765696, 608583.734491 127621.137605)'
```

which is a valid linestring.

More info on string on string functions and operators can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html).

Comment: Thanks! it solved to problem :) for some weird reason it shows me that result is empty but when i go inside the table is fine.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with your result without seeing the data but I'm glad my answer helped

Comment: Do you know if i can load view table inside qgis?

Comment: You can, just follow the same procedure as you would for a table. You have to also include a primary key column in your view.